# running migration on development rails env does not show any errors and does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails web application with mysql as my database. I wanna add a column to an existing table in a development server. The problem is that when I run rake db:migrate it starts and does not complete the migration without showing any errors. There is no difference if I add RAILS_ENV=development.
Please pay attention that my db is called maha_production and I do not want to change it to maha_development. If it matters.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
rake db:migrate
== 20210302055219 AddUidRelatedToArticle: migrating ==========================
-- add_column(:articles, :uid_related, :string, {:after=>:uid,index=>true})
```

and it stops in this state for hours...

The migration is

```
class AddUidRelatedToArticle < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :articles, :uid_related, :string ,after: :uid, index: true
    add_index :articles, :uid_related
  end
end
```

Here is config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development: &development
  <<: *default
  database: maha_production
  username: maha
  password:  <%= ENV['MAHA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>


production: &production
  <<: *default
  database: maha_production
  username: maha
  password: <%= ENV['MAHA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

data_refinement_development:
  <<: *default
  database: data_refinement_development

data_refinement_production:
  <<: *production
  database: data_refinement

logs_production:
  <<: *production
  database: maha_logs
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the migration and `config/database.yml` to the question?

Comment: yes, I did, is there anything wrong?:(

Comment: Nothing obvious, though I think `after: :uid` will get ignored. I suspect maybe an issue with MySQL. Do you have a rails server running too or several consoles? Could be running short of connections. Otherwise, I suggest running an db admin tool and see what MySQL is doing while it is hanging.

Comment: I can see development.log , if helps , saying 
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError (

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run:

 bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development)

Thank you for your suggestions,  I will try a db admin tool, I can access the server through several terminals if you mean it.